# :Explore shows the "." directory

Tags: netrw

Why does the `:Explore` command shows the `.` directory? This seems  to be unnecessary as it's just one more line that I have to `j`.

Is there some way I can disable this?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you mean by "the `:E` explorer mode"? On my system it doesn't seems the a `:E` command exists: all I have is the `:Explore` command and it doesn't show a `.` directory.

Comment: Yes, I do mean the :Explore command. So looks like there is something wrong with my vim or system settings.

Comment: Have you tried using Tim Pope's [vinegar plugin](https://github.com/tpope/vim-vinegar.git)? It really improves `netrw` behavior. I'm not sure it is what makes the `.` directory disappear but it is generally a good plugin to use if you use `netrw`.

Comment: I can't answer the "how do I hide it"-part, but as for the "why"-part: it allows you to do operations on the current directory. Is this really *that* useful in netrw? Not really if you ask me. But that's probably the reason why it's there...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could hide the dot directory (`./`) by setting the global variables `g:netrw_list_hide` and `g:netrw_hide` in your `vimrc` like this:

```
let g:netrw_list_hide = '^\./$'
let g:netrw_hide = 1
```

The first variable can contain a comma separated list of regex patterns describing what you want to hide.  Here, the pattern used is `'^\./$'`:
a beginning of string (`^`), a literal dot `\.`, a slash `/` and an end of string `$`.

You can also edit this variable from the file explorer netrw, by hitting `<C-h>`.

Once the variable is set, from netrw, hitting `a` will switch between different views:

- showing everything
- hiding items described by `g:netrw_list_hide`
- only showing items in `g:netrw_list_hide`

You can configure which view is chosen by default by setting up `g:netrw_hide` which can take 3 values (`0`, `1` or `2`).
`1` means hiding by default the items in `g:netrw_list_hide`.

---

For more information, see:

```
:help g:netrw_list_hide
:help g:netrw_hide
```

Comment: Just checked on a friends machine. I think it should be hidden and not even show up. I think I might have messed up some defaults.

Comment: Why are you deleting answers, saginaw? O.o OP just reposted this on [unix.se] (http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/269307/70524), and going by that post, your current answer is what he's looking for.

Comment: I thought the problem was in a default setting that was misconfigured and that the answer didn't solve the issue, sorry.